# Bigquery SQL to Generate a mixed-level factorial designs array- Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have `Table1` that contains a variable number of tasks. Each task may have different options in `Table2`.

For this example,

- `Task id = 1` has two possible options
- `Task id = 2` has two possible options
- `Task id = 3` has only 1 possible option
- `Task id = 4` has only 1 possible option

How to build a bigquery SQL to obtain the cartesian product of all possible combinations?

The output would be as shown in the Output table below, where Run is the number of a possible combination between the Tasks options.

Table1

```
Taskid  Name
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
```

Table2

```
Taskid  Optionid    Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3  
1          1           5           7           9
1          2           2           4           6
2          1           4           6           8
2          2           2           4           8
3          1           1           4           9
4          1           4           7           10
```

Output Table

```
Run Taskid  Name    Optionid    Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3
1     1     A          1           5           7           9
1     2     B          1           4           6           8
1     3     C          1           1           4           9
1     4     D          1           4           7           10
2     1     A          1           5           7           9
2     2     B          2           2           4           8
2     3     C          1           1           4           9
2     4     D          1           4           7           10
3     1     A          2           2           4           6
3     2     B          1           4           6           8
3     3     C          1           1           4           9
3     4     D          1           4           7           10
4     1     A          2           2           4           6
4     2     B          2           2           4           8
4     3     C          1           1           4           9
4     4     D          1           4           7           10
```

I have managed to create the combinations in MS Access query using pivot. Please see below at the bottom of the question where added the MS Access queries to generate the combinations. However, this is limited to 4 tasks, is there a way to scale it to account for any number of tasks and have it all in Bigquery?

MS Access query #1 (CTQ):

```
TRANSFORM First(VariableT.[Optionid]) AS [FirstOfOption id]
SELECT Table2.[Optionid]
FROM VariableT
GROUP BY Table2.[Optionid]
PIVOT Table2.[Taskid];
```

MS Access query #2 (this generates the combinations):

```
SELECT CTQ.[1], CTQ_1.[2], CTQ_2.[3], CTQ_3.[4]
FROM  CTQ, CTQ AS CTQ_1, CTQ AS CTQ_2, CTQ AS CTQ_3
GROUP BY CTQ.[1], CTQ_1.[2], CTQ_2.[3], CTQ_3.[4]
HAVING (((CTQ.[1]) Is Not Null) AND ((CTQ_1.[2]) Is Not Null) 
AND ((CTQ_2.[3]) Is Not Null) AND ((CTQ_3.[4]) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: i have been trying all day but with no luck to get the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really enjoyed this "exercise"
Ended up being relatively skin and simple, but with limitations because of use of JS UDF. For big sets might have memory related issues

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION generateCombinations(taskOptions ARRAY<STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var arr = [];  
  for (i = 0; i < taskOptions.length; i++) { 
    arr.push(taskOptions[i].opts);
  }
  return cartesianProduct(arr).join('|');
  function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
  }
""";
WITH combinations AS (
  SELECT generateCombinations(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>(TaskId, opts) ORDER BY Taskid)) arr
  FROM (SELECT Taskid, ARRAY_AGG(Optionid) opts FROM `yourproject.youdataset.table2` GROUP BY Taskid)
), runs AS (
  SELECT Run + 1 Run, combination 
  FROM combinations, UNNEST(SPLIT(arr, '|')) combination WITH OFFSET Run
)
SELECT Run, t1.Taskid, Name, Optionid, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
FROM runs, UNNEST(SPLIT(combination)) oid WITH OFFSET tid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table2` t2 ON t2.Taskid = tid + 1 AND CAST(Optionid AS STRING) = oid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table1` t1 ON t1.Taskid = tid + 1
-- ORDER BY Run, Taskid
```

you can test / play with above using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION generateCombinations(taskOptions ARRAY<STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var arr = [];  
  for (i = 0; i < taskOptions.length; i++) { 
    arr.push(taskOptions[i].opts);
  }
  return cartesianProduct(arr).join('|');
  function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
  }
""";
WITH `yourproject.youdataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 Taskid, 'A' Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'D' 
), `yourproject.youdataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 Taskid, 1 Optionid, 5 Attribute1, 7 Attribute2, 9 Attribute3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 2, 4, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 4, 6, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 2, 4, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 1, 4, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 4, 7, 10 
), combinations AS (
  SELECT generateCombinations(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>(TaskId, opts) ORDER BY Taskid)) arr
  FROM (SELECT Taskid, ARRAY_AGG(Optionid) opts FROM `yourproject.youdataset.table2` GROUP BY Taskid)
), runs AS (
  SELECT Run + 1 Run, combination 
  FROM combinations, UNNEST(SPLIT(arr, '|')) combination WITH OFFSET Run
)
SELECT Run, t1.Taskid, Name, Optionid, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
FROM runs, UNNEST(SPLIT(combination)) oid WITH OFFSET tid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table2` t2 ON t2.Taskid = tid + 1 AND CAST(Optionid AS STRING) = oid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table1` t1 ON t1.Taskid = tid + 1
ORDER BY Run, Taskid
```

output here is exactly as in expected output of your question

> I have run your query with 19 tasks having multiple option levels for up to 5 options and the query returned "Error: Request timed out."

As I mentioned - the main limitation here is [`output to be approximately 5MB or less`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits). 
Of course with 19 tasks and up to 5 options for each - the output will be much larger than 5MB if you to try to process them in one run. Btw, the max I was able to process using above approach in one run was 7 tasks with 5 options each or 10 tasks with 2 to 5 options each.

So, the "workaround" for you would be - instead of running all tasks in one run - you can split your tasks to let's say four groups with respectively 5 tasks with up to 5 options in each group. Then you can run above for each group with separate destination table (`yourproject.youdataset.run1`, `yourproject.youdataset.run2`, `yourproject.youdataset.run3`, `yourproject.youdataset.run4`) for each group thus materializing virtual table "runs" from initial answer .

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION generateCombinations(taskOptions ARRAY<STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var arr = [];  
  for (i = 0; i < taskOptions.length; i++) { 
    arr.push(taskOptions[i].opts);
  }
  return cartesianProduct(arr).join('|');
  function cartesianProduct(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
  }
""";
WITH combinations AS (
  SELECT generateCombinations(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<Taskid INT64, opts ARRAY<INT64>>(TaskId, opts) ORDER BY Taskid)) arr
  FROM (SELECT Taskid, ARRAY_AGG(Optionid) opts FROM `yourproject.youdataset.table2` GROUP BY Taskid)
), runs AS (
  SELECT Run + 1 Run, combination 
  FROM combinations, UNNEST(SPLIT(arr, '|')) combination WITH OFFSET Run
)
SELECT *
FROM runs
```

And finally, you can cross join these four tables to get final set of all combinations. This will give you final materialized table for "runs" - `yourproject.youdataset.run`. After you got it  - now you can apply the rest of query

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH runs AS (
  SELECT Run, combination 
  FROM `yourproject.youdataset.run`
)
SELECT Run, t1.Taskid, Name, Optionid, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3
FROM runs, UNNEST(SPLIT(combination)) oid WITH OFFSET tid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table2` t2 ON t2.Taskid = tid + 1 AND CAST(Optionid AS STRING) = oid
JOIN `yourproject.youdataset.table1` t1 ON t1.Taskid = tid + 1
```

Note: above is outline of workaround - less likely but you might need to do some some minor adjustments along the road here.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the Prompt answer. You are right about the memory limitation, i have run your query with 19 tasks having multiple option levels for up to 5 options and the query returned "Error: Request timed out.". Is there away to avoid creating the combinations using a JS UDF ? i have managed to create the combinations in MSAccess Query using Pivot. Please see my edits at the bottom of the Question where added the MS Access Queries to generate the combinations. However, this is limited to 4 Tasks, is there a way to scale it to account for any number of Tasks and have it all in Bigquery.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, Thanks for explaining the limitations. Is it possible to do this in google sheets app script, where the table is read from a sheet, broken down to the 5 tasks group, running the bigquery for the sets in parallel, and write append the results in one bigquery table. might sound like too much to ask, but this will result in an automation for the bigquery runs and get the results in one click.